# Unmelt only part of a column from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, melt

I have the following example dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'RecordID' : [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5], 'DisplayLabel' : ['Source','Test','Value 1','Value 2','Value3','Source','Test','Value 1','Value 2','Source','Test','Value 1','Value 2','Source','Test','Value 1','Value 2','Source','Test','Value 1','Value 2'],
'Value' : ['Web','Logic','S','I','Complete','Person','Voice','>20','P','Mail','OCR','A','I','Dictation','Understandable','S','I','Web','Logic','R','S']})
```

which creates this dataframe:

```
+-------+----------+---------------+----------------+
| Index | RecordID | Display Label |     Value      |
+-------+----------+---------------+----------------+
|     0 |        1 | Source        | Web            |
|     1 |        1 | Test          | Logic          |
|     2 |        1 | Value 1       | S              |
|     3 |        1 | Value 2       | I              |
|     4 |        1 | Value 3       | Complete       |
|     5 |        2 | Source        | Person         |
|     6 |        2 | Test          | Voice          |
|     7 |        2 | Value 1       | >20            |
|     8 |        2 | Value 2       | P              |
|     9 |        3 | Source        | Mail           |
|    10 |        3 | Test          | OCR            |
|    11 |        3 | Value 1       | A              |
|    12 |        3 | Value 2       | I              |
|    13 |        4 | Source        | Dictation      |
|    14 |        4 | Test          | Understandable |
|    15 |        4 | Value 1       | S              |
|    16 |        4 | Value 2       | I              |
|    17 |        5 | Source        | Web            |
|    18 |        5 | Test          | Logic          |
|    19 |        5 | Value 1       | R              |
|    20 |        5 | Value 2       | S              |
+-------+----------+---------------+----------------+
```

I am trying to "unmelt" though not exactly the source and test columns into new dataframe Columns such that it will look like this:

```
+-------+----------+-----------+----------------+---------------+----------+
| Index | RecordID |  Source   |      Test      | Result        |  Value   |
+-------+----------+-----------+----------------+---------------+----------+
|     0 |        1 | Web       | Logic          | Value 1       | S        |
|     1 |        1 | Web       | Logic          | Value 2       | I        |
|     2 |        1 | Web       | Logic          | Value 3       | Complete |
|     3 |        2 | Person    | Voice          | Value 1       | >20      |
|     4 |        2 | Person    | Voice          | Value 2       | P        |
|     5 |        3 | Mail      | OCR            | Value 1       | A        |
|     6 |        3 | Mail      | OCR            | Value 2       | I        |
|     7 |        4 | Dictation | Understandable | Value 1       | S        |
|     8 |        4 | Dictation | Understandable | Value 2       | I        |
|     9 |        5 | Web       | Logic          | Value 1       | R        |
|    10 |        5 | Web       | Logic          | Value 2       | S        |
+-------+----------+-----------+----------------+---------------+----------+
```

It's my understanding that pivot and melt will do the entire DisplayLabel column and not just some of the values.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have read the [Pandas Melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) and the [Pandas Pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot.html#pandas.pivot)  as well as some references on stackoverflow and I can't seem to figure out a way to do this quickly.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you know which Test a Result in your original DataFrame is associated with? For example in index 2, how do you know that `Value 1` goes under the `Logic` Test row in your second DataFrame?

Comment: Hi nathan!  I had made a mistake in the final table, as the record IDs group all of the source and values together.  Apologies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can achieve your result by applying logic and pivotting, we split your data by checking if `DisplayLabel` contains `Value` and then we `join` them back together:

```
mask = df['DisplayLabel'].str.contains('Value')
df2 = df[~mask].pivot(index='RecordID', columns='DisplayLabel', values='Value')

dfpiv = (
    df[mask].rename(columns={'DisplayLabel':'Result'})
            .set_index('RecordID')
            .join(df2)
            .reset_index()
)
```

```
    RecordID   Result     Value     Source            Test
0          1  Value 1         S        Web           Logic
1          1  Value 2         I        Web           Logic
2          1   Value3  Complete        Web           Logic
3          2  Value 1       >20     Person           Voice
4          2  Value 2         P     Person           Voice
5          3  Value 1         A       Mail             OCR
6          3  Value 2         I       Mail             OCR
7          4  Value 1         S  Dictation  Understandable
8          4  Value 2         I  Dictation  Understandable
9          5  Value 1         R        Web           Logic
10         5  Value 2         S        Web           Logic
```

---

If you want the exact column order as your example, use `DataFrame.reindex`:

```
dfpiv.reindex(columns=['RecordID', 'Source', 'Test', 'Result', 'Value'])
```

```
    RecordID     Source            Test   Result     Value
0          1        Web           Logic  Value 1         S
1          1        Web           Logic  Value 2         I
2          1        Web           Logic   Value3  Complete
3          2     Person           Voice  Value 1       >20
4          2     Person           Voice  Value 2         P
5          3       Mail             OCR  Value 1         A
6          3       Mail             OCR  Value 2         I
7          4  Dictation  Understandable  Value 1         S
8          4  Dictation  Understandable  Value 2         I
9          5        Web           Logic  Value 1         R
10         5        Web           Logic  Value 2         S
```

---

#### In detail - step by step:

```
# mask all rows where "Value" is in column DisplayLabel
mask = df['DisplayLabel'].str.contains('Value')

0     False
1     False
2      True
3      True
4      True
5     False
6     False
7      True
8      True
9     False
10    False
11     True
12     True
13    False
14    False
15     True
16     True
17    False
18    False
19     True
20     True
Name: DisplayLabel, dtype: bool
```

```
# select all rows which do NOT have "Value" in DisplayLabel
df[~mask]

    RecordID DisplayLabel           Value
0          1       Source             Web
1          1         Test           Logic
5          2       Source          Person
6          2         Test           Voice
9          3       Source            Mail
10         3         Test             OCR
13         4       Source       Dictation
14         4         Test  Understandable
17         5       Source             Web
18         5         Test           Logic
```

```
# pivot the values in DisplayLabel to columns
df2 = df[~mask].pivot(index='RecordID', columns='DisplayLabel', values='Value')

DisplayLabel     Source            Test
RecordID                               
1                   Web           Logic
2                Person           Voice
3                  Mail             OCR
4             Dictation  Understandable
5                   Web           Logic
```

```
df[mask].rename(columns={'DisplayLabel':'Result'}) # rename the column DisplayLabel to Result
            .set_index('RecordID')                 # set RecordId as index so we can join df2 
            .join(df2)                             # join df2 back to our dataframe based RecordId
            .reset_index()                         # reset index so we get RecordId back as column

    RecordID   Result     Value     Source            Test
0          1  Value 1         S        Web           Logic
1          1  Value 2         I        Web           Logic
2          1   Value3  Complete        Web           Logic
3          2  Value 1       >20     Person           Voice
4          2  Value 2         P     Person           Voice
5          3  Value 1         A       Mail             OCR
6          3  Value 2         I       Mail             OCR
7          4  Value 1         S  Dictation  Understandable
8          4  Value 2         I  Dictation  Understandable
9          5  Value 1         R        Web           Logic
10         5  Value 2         S        Web           Logic
```

Comment: Can you please detail out what your steps are doing?  I think I follow, but for me and other people on StackOverflow, it might be very helpful.  Particularly, if you have more columns, how would you modify it.  Thanks so much for the solution!

Comment: Sure, see edit, I wrote an extensive in detail explanation. Hope this helps @Jon

Comment: Thanks some much @Erfan!  I am running into a weird error when I get to the pivot step,  I keep getting this: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

#### `set_index`, `unstack`, then `melt`

```
df.set_index(['RecordID', 'DisplayLabel']).Value.unstack().reset_index() \
  .melt(['RecordID', 'Source', 'Test'], var_name='Result', value_name='Value') \
  .sort_values('RecordID').dropna(subset=['Value'])

    RecordID     Source            Test   Result     Value
0          1        Web           Logic  Value 1         S
5          1        Web           Logic  Value 2         I
10         1        Web           Logic  Value 3  Complete
1          2     Person           Voice  Value 1       >20
6          2     Person           Voice  Value 2         P
2          3       Mail             OCR  Value 1         A
7          3       Mail             OCR  Value 2         I
3          4  Dictation  Understandable  Value 1         S
8          4  Dictation  Understandable  Value 2         I
4          5        Web           Logic  Value 1         R
9          5        Web           Logic  Value 2         S
```

---

#### Custom function for `groupby`

```
def f(t):
    name, df = t
    d = dict(zip(df['DisplayLabel'], df['Value']))
    source = d.pop('Source')
    test = d.pop('Test')
    result, value = zip(*d.items())

    return pd.DataFrame(
        dict(RecordID=name, Source=source, Test=test, Result=result, Value=value)
    )

pd.concat(map(f, df.groupby('RecordID')))

   RecordID     Source            Test   Result     Value
0         1        Web           Logic  Value 1         S
1         1        Web           Logic  Value 2         I
2         1        Web           Logic  Value 3  Complete
0         2     Person           Voice  Value 1       >20
1         2     Person           Voice  Value 2         P
0         3       Mail             OCR  Value 1         A
1         3       Mail             OCR  Value 2         I
0         4  Dictation  Understandable  Value 1         S
1         4  Dictation  Understandable  Value 2         I
0         5        Web           Logic  Value 1         R
1         5        Web           Logic  Value 2         S
```

---

#### Setup

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'RecordID': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5],
    'DisplayLabel': [
        'Source', 'Test', 'Value 1', 'Value 2', 'Value 3',
        'Source', 'Test', 'Value 1', 'Value 2',
        'Source', 'Test', 'Value 1', 'Value 2',
        'Source', 'Test', 'Value 1', 'Value 2',
        'Source', 'Test', 'Value 1', 'Value 2'
    ],
    'Value': [
        'Web', 'Logic', 'S', 'I', 'Complete',
        'Person', 'Voice', '>20', 'P',
        'Mail', 'OCR', 'A', 'I',
        'Dictation', 'Understandable', 'S', 'I',
        'Web', 'Logic', 'R', 'S'
    ]
})
```

Comment: Can you please detail out what your steps are doing?  I think I follow, but for me and other people on StackOverflow, it might be very helpful.  Particularly, if you have more columns, how would you modify it.  Thanks so much for the solution!

Answer (score 0):

I tried a different approach of first `pivot`ing using `unstack` and then partially converting `wide_to_long` (Sorry if it's not efficient but this seems to get the desired output)

```py
# first converting all long to wide
df2 = df.set_index(['RecordID','DisplayLabel']).unstack()
# flattening the unstacked columns
df2.columns = df2.columns.to_series().str.join('_')
df2.columns = df2.columns.str.replace('Value_','',regex=True) #just removing the junk in the column name
df2 = df2.reset_index() #resetting index to access RecordID

df2 = (pd.melt(df2,id_vars=['RecordID',"Source","Test"],var_name='Result', value_name='Value')
.sort_values(['RecordID',"Source","Test"])
.dropna()
.reset_index())
```

```
index   RecordID    Source  Test    Result  Value
0   0   1   Web Logic   Value 1 S
1   5   1   Web Logic   Value 2 I
2   10  1   Web Logic   Value 3 Complete
3   1   2   Person  Voice   Value 1 >20
4   6   2   Person  Voice   Value 2 P
5   2   3   Mail    OCR Value 1 A
6   7   3   Mail    OCR Value 2 I
7   3   4   Dictation   Understandable  Value 1 S
8   8   4   Dictation   Understandable  Value 2 I
9   4   5   Web Logic   Value 1 R
10  9   5   Web Logic   Value 2 S
```